# How to display a page after a get request received?

Tags: javascript, node.js, express

I am trying to display a page after a get request received. For example, some user send a get request to my server, ('/home') and I want to display home page after that.

I tried res.render but it doesn't change the page. It only send url back.

```
fetch('lom').then((res)=>{

        console.log(res);

}); //GET Request
```

```
app.get('/lom',(req,res)=>{

    res.render('lom');

}); // Respond
```

I expect to see /home page after request but current page is not changing.
I don't want to use window.location.href = '/lom'. I want to change page in server side.

Comment: Are you actually trying to load the url via ajax here rather than navigating to a new page. If you're trying to use server side then just use an `<a>` tag

Comment: Are you using any template engine like ejs?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're using `fetch`.

The **entire** point of using `fetch` is that the browser **doesn't** navigate to a new page, and the response is processed using JavaScript instead.

Use a regular link. Submit a form. Use `window.location.href = '/lom'` (I know you said you didn't *want* to, but not *wanting* to do the right thing is a terrible reason not to do it). But do something which causes the browser to navigate. `fetch` is the *wrong tool for the job*.

> I want to change page in server-side.

There is no way to trigger navigation in the browser directly from the server-side. There needs to be something on the client designed to navigate (this might be triggered by client-side code based on data in a response from the server, but it still needs to be client-side).

Comment: Thank you. That was really helpful.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if I fully undestand your problem, at any rate, take a look at below code, a **res.send** command sending content to be displayed (https://expressjs.com/en/guide/routing.html).

```
app.get('/', function (req, res) {
  res.send('root')
})
```

I'd recommend to interest in a template engines 
https://expressjs.com/en/advanced/developing-template-engines.html

Answer (score 0):

Fetch is going to do only XMLHttpRequest request to 'lom' (ajax call), which not supposed to redirect your page but to receive just the response in your res parameter.

```
fetch('/lom').then((res)=>{

        console.log(res);

}); //GET Request
```

So you will see your response in your browser console tab by doing console.log. Anyway if you want to do a redirection do it in the client side, for ex: window.location = '/home'.